# if statement to assign values to dataframe on the basis of other values in the dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to assign a string character ("LI", "HI", or "MID") in the column "impulsivity" on the basis of numbers in the column "rat_ID".

I thought of doing this with an if statement but I can't get it to work

```
mydat1 <- data.frame("rat_ID" = 1:6, "Prem" = c(0,0,0,1,0,1), "Corr" = c(1,1,0,0,0,0), "Incorr" = c(0,0,0,0,1,0))

mydat1$rat_ID = as.numeric(mydat1$rat_ID)

for (i in length(mydat1$Corr)) {
  if (mydat1$rat_ID[i]==1 | mydat1$rat_ID[i]==6) {
  mydat1$impulsivity[i] = 'HI'
} else if (mydat1$rat_ID[i]==3 | mydat1$rat_ID[i]==4) {
  mydat1$impulsivity[i] = 'LI'
} else {
  mydat1$impulsivity[i] = 'MID'
} 
}
```

For some reason it gives NA values for most animals and "HI" to rat #6.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it gives you `NA` for all values except the last value is because your loop is running only for last value. In your `for` loop do

```
for (i in 1:length(mydat1$Corr)) {
  .....
  .....
```

---

Apart from the `for` loop there are other approaches which you can consider. One with `dplyr` , `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

mydat1 %>%
   mutate(impulsivity = case_when(rat_ID %in% c(1, 6) ~ "HI", 
                                  rat_ID %in% c(3, 4) ~"LI", 
                                  TRUE ~ "MID"))

#  rat_ID Prem Corr Incorr impulsivity
#1      1    0    1      0          HI
#2      2    0    1      0         MID
#3      3    0    0      0          LI
#4      4    1    0      0          LI
#5      5    0    0      1         MID
#6      6    1    0      0          HI
```

OR `ifelse` in base R

```
mydat1$impulsivity <- with(mydat1, ifelse(rat_ID %in% c(1, 6), "HI",
                      ifelse(rat_ID %in% c(3, 4), "LI", "MID")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case_when` from the dplyr package for example

```
> library(dplyr)
> mydat1 <- data.frame("rat_ID" = 1:6, "Prem" = c(0,0,0,1,0,1), "Corr" = c(1,1,0,0,0,0), "Incorr" = c(0,0,0,0,1,0))
> mydat1$rat_ID = as.numeric(mydat1$rat_ID)
> mydat1 %>% mutate(Impulsivity = case_when(rat_ID %in% c(1, 6) ~ 'low',
+                                           rat_ID == 5 ~ 'high',
+                                           TRUE ~ 'something else'))
  rat_ID Prem Corr Incorr    Impulsivity
1      1    0    1      0            low
2      2    0    1      0 something else
3      3    0    0      0 something else
4      4    1    0      0 something else
5      5    0    0      1           high
6      6    1    0      0            low
```